# Why is footskip ignored in my presentation?

Tags: beamer, margins

This is the very first beamer presentation I am building, and when I tried to increase the bottom margin using `\addtolength{\footskip}`, there was no effect whatsoever.

```
\documentclass[12pt,table]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=25mm,text margin right=25mm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\date{11/15/2017}

\addtolength{\headsep}{0.6cm} % to increase top margin in beamer

\begin{document}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.6cm} % to increase bottom margin in beamer

    \maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use the relevant Beamer dimensions and the proper key-value interface. Note that your changes make no sense as is: you are increasing two vertical dimensions without either increasing the paper height or decreasing any other dimension. So this will end in tears even in a more standard class. Why aren't you using `frame`? This seems to be a very odd presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase distance between your text and the top of the frame, you could add extra vertical space to either the headline or the frametitle (depending if the space should be above of below the frametitle).

However a bottom margin does not really make sense in beamer. If you put too much text in a frame, it will just overflow at the bottom, no matter if there is a margin or not.

```
\documentclass[12pt,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vspace*{1cm}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-1cm}}{\vspace*{1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```